# Does using GameKit / Game Center in your app increase its binary size?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, gamekit

I'm looking to implement Game Center features into my iOS app; however, I'm not sure how much it will increase my application's binary filesize.  There seem to be a lot of features in GameKit which I won't be using because I only want to use achievements and leaderboards.  Is there a way to leave out the unused features at compile time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual code for frameworks is not copied into your program. The linker builds symbolic links into your executable code that enables it to find the frameworks on the deployment platform (iPhone, iPad, etc) at runtime.

The only increase in your program size will come from code you actually write to use the GameKit (for example your leaderboard or P2P code).

Comment: So why aren't frameworks linked by default or automatically? I mean every time we have to do this? and many questions come from link errors.

Comment: It wouldn't be efficient to link to every possible dynamic framework. Apart from wasting space in the executable, it would also increase the startup time of your program, and waste RAM (as the OS will attempt to load all the required frameworks defined in the executable).

Answer (score 2):

Linking to iOS frameworks does not increase the size of your binary by any substantial amount. Those frameworks are all already on the device, as part of the operating system, so applications which link to them don't include the library in the app itself, they just load it from the shared location on the device.